# DRF and Knox showing logged in user as anonymous (Django)

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-knox

I created an API with DRF and Knox and, I am using token based authentication. Everything is working except the system is showing the logged in user as anonymous.

I tried all this:

```
            current_user = request.user
            print(current_user.is_anonymous) # True
            print(current_user.is_authenticated) # False
            print(current_user.is_staff) # False
            print(current_user.is_superuser) # false
            print(current_user.is_active) # false

            u = User()
            print(u.id) # None
```

I need the user id of the logged in user because I am using that as a foreign key in the other table. I checked the auth_user table and it has all the columns. Is there any way to get the user id or convert the anonymous user to authenticated user ?

Thanks
AJ

Answer (score 1):

```
from knox.auth import TokenAuthentication
token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', False)
if token:
    token = str(token).split()[1].encode("utf-8")
    knoxAuth = TokenAuthentication()
    user, auth_token = knoxAuth.authenticate_credentials(token)
    request.user = user
```

Comment: You have to run this code for every single view endpoint that you'd want the request.user from? What's the point of having a request.user if it's not going to auto-populate itself?